# Exceptions using requests only in run mode

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm

I have simpe code which make request to different services and if response code != 200 send request to another service:

```
for section in config.sections():
            print(f"[{section}]")
            service_url = config.get(section, 'service_url', fallback=None)
            company_service = config.get(section, 'company_service', fallback=None)
            login = config.get(section, 'user', fallback=None)
            password = config.get(section, 'password', fallback=None)
            try:
                response = requests.get(service_url, auth=(login, password), timeout=10)
                resp_code = response.status_code
                resp_time = response.elapsed.total_seconds()
                print(f"[{resp_code} : {resp_time}]")
                status = "available"  # lages
                if resp_code != 200:
                    status = "disabled"
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(f"Exception while request: {e}")
                status = "disabled"
```

in config there're 10 services and in run mode (shift+F10) I have exception for every service
Exception while request: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'the remote host forcibly closed the existing connection', None, 10054, None))
but in debug mode (shift+F9) everything is ok, I get response code and different elapsed time for services? What is the problem in run mode?